# Pass parameters (left, top values) in window.open method with javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does an absolute value (i.e. left=400) work in the window.open method but passing a variable doesnt? (see code below):

```
function openwindow(){

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var wc= (w - 200); 
var hc= (h - 200);  

var strWindowFeatures = " toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=400,left=wc";
window.open("pop-up.html","mywindow", strWindowFeatures);
}
```

Also what doesnt seem to work is:
a. toolbar (url bar) still shows up
b. based on this url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

the centerscreen feature should work... (although does not state browser support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `"wc"`, not the value of `wc`. Change this:

```
"....,left=wc";
```

to

```
"....,left=" + wc;
```

Comment: correct, it works. Also corrected the centering code: wc= (w/2) - 200. Any ideas about the other features mentioned above?